# How does one read/write memory on a PCI device in VxWorks 653?

Tags: vxworks, pci

I'm using VxWorks 653, and my target is the wrSbc7457 Power PC.

I have a mezzanine card on my wrSbc7457, and I'm trying to write/read the memory on that mezzanine card.

For those of you familiar with VxWorks, I have the following in the `usrAppInit()` function of my ModuleOS:

```
printf ( "Entering ModuleOS, usrAppInit() ...\n" ) ;
printf ( "sysModel() returns %s\n", sysModel() ) ;
pciDeviceShow ( 0 ) ;


{
int pciBus, pciDevice, pciFunc ;
UINT32  BAR_0_contents, BAR_1_contents ;

printf
    ( "\npciFindDevice returns STATUS %d\n",
            pciFindDevice ( my_VENDORID, my_PMC_DEVICEID, 0, &pciBus, &pciDevice, &pciFunc )
    ) ;
printf ( "\tand pciBus = %d, pciDevice = %d, pciFunc = %d\n", pciBus, pciDevice, pciFunc ) ;

printf ( "\npciConfigInLong returns STATUS %d\n",
        pciConfigInLong ( pciBus, pciDevice, pciFunc, PCI_CFG_BASE_ADDRESS_0, & BAR_0_contents ) ) ;
printf ( "\tand Base Address Register 0 contains 0x%X\n", BAR_0_contents ) ;
printf ( "\npciConfigInLong returns STATUS %d\n",
        pciConfigInLong ( pciBus, pciDevice, pciFunc, PCI_CFG_BASE_ADDRESS_1, & BAR_1_contents ) ) ;
printf ( "\tand Base Address Register 1 contains 0x%X\n", BAR_1_contents ) ;
```

My target outputs the following when the OS boot image is loaded:

```
Entering ModuleOS, usrAppInit() ...

sysModel() returns wrSbc7457 Power PC

Scanning function 0 of each PCI device on bus 0
Using configuration mechanism 0
bus       device    function  vendorID  deviceID  class
00000000  00000000  00000000  0000----  0000----  000-----
00000000  00000001  00000000  0000----  0000----  00--0000
00000000  00000002  00000000  0000----  0000----  000-----

pciFindDevice returns STATUS 0 (OK)
        and pciBus = 0, pciDevice = 1, pciFunc = 0

pciConfigInLong returns STATUS 0 (OK)
        and Base Address Register 0 contains 0x50000000

pciConfigInLong returns STATUS 0 (OK)
        and Base Address Register 1 contains 0x58000000
```

My question is:  how do I map the memory of my mezzanine card into my host's address space, and then how do I write/read the memory on that mezzanine card?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no universal answer.  You have to program the PCI bridge.
Some of it depends if you use the PCI auto configuration or not.

You should look at the library references for pciConfig and/or pciAutoConfig.

Your device looks like it has two address spaces at 0x50000000 and 0x58000000, but I believe that's the PCI address space, not the host bridge mapping.